# How to get the value stored in __proto__ Object?

Tags: javascript, prototype, puppeteer, prototypal-inheritance

I am new to JavaScript and using Puppeteer for web scraping.  I was trying to understand the `__proto__` object.

I have a Map.

```
var invoiceMap = new Map();
```

Next I have a promise which resolve to `data.invoiceMap`.

```
data.invoiceMap[obj.emp.id] = obj.emp.blob;

resolve(data.invoiceMap);
```

Now when I evaluate the expression - `data["1"]`. It gives me a `__proto__` Object.

How can I find the blob value stored against the EmpId = 1? OR How to get the `invoiceMap` object associated with `data` ?.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
const data = await page.evaluate(async function(invoices) {
        return await  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {            
            var data = invoices;
            document.addEventListener('empInvoice', (obj) => {
                data.invoiceMap[obj.emp.id] = obj.emp.blob;
                resolve(data.invoiceMap);
            })
        });
    }, {
        invoiceMap: invoiceMap
    });
```

Comment: What is `data.invoiceMap`?

Comment: @VLAZ I have edited the question. Hope that will help you understand the problem.

Comment: If `invoiceMap` is indeed a map, then why do you use `data.invoiceMap[obj.emp.id] = obj.emp.blob`? In order to add values to a map, you need to use [the `.set()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set). Moreover, this is invoking a function through (I assume) Puppeteer yet nowhere did you specify that. These functions have quite a lot of oddities to them, as they are transformed and re-evaluated into an entirely different environment then the result transformed back as well. I'm not even sure prototypes are at play there or if so - how.

Comment: Yes. It is Puppeteer which I am using for web scrapping.

Comment: Then you really *should* have started with this and mentioned it in the tags. I've almost no experience with Puppeteer other than the knowledge that functions given to `page.evaluate` behave oddly due to the serialisation/deserialisation they go through. This makes the question specialised to people more familiar with Puppeteer than just anybody who knows JavaScript or prototypes. As I said, I don't even know what happens with the prototype chain of values that are serialised. I assume it's wiped but I'm not really sure.

Comment: What happens when you console.log `data`? It looks like you are returning an "awaited promise". Adding `async` to a function wraps your function in a promise so you don't need to create a new one. My guess is pupeteer is returning a wrapped promise (that wasn't called) and is pointing to _proto_ because everything in JS is an object. I'd remove the await before your Promise, or remove the promise and just return your logic